# ZPool export from USB to SATA

Tags: zfs

I have a zpool imported with /dev/disk/by-id. This zpool consists of 2 disks connected via USB (with SATA hard drive adapters).

The status of the zpool looks like this:

```
NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
sbizsafe                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
    usb-SABRENT_SABRENT_DB9876543214E-0:0       ONLINE       0     0     0
    usb-TO_Exter_nal_USB_3.0_201503310007F-0:0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

What I would like to do is to move the zpool to anoter computer where the hard drives will be connected directly to SATA. Will the import by-id work on the new machine even if the ids will be different?

Answer (score 1):

Worked with this command:

```
zpool import -a
```